# FLVPLAYBACK Fullscreen problem with IE/Vista

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I'm having a problem making my `FlvPlayback` go full screen.

in FF it works great but in IE (8) it will only work once! the next time, it will flicker and return to normal state.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How are you embedding the swf file?

It could be the difference in  and  with IE causing the problem.

An easy fix may be to use SWFObject http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

This is a JavaScript file that automates the swf embed based on browser. It may be worth a try because it can fix browser issues with swf files.

It is used as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

    var so = new SWFObject("main.swf", "mainMovie", "100%", "100%", "9", "#083770");
    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    so.addParam("quality", "high");
    so.addParam("allowScriptAccess","always");
    so.write("flashcontent");
```

Thus the script places the swf in the appropriate tags for the browser being used.

Comment: Thanks. actualy, I am using swfObject. The issue is not the element, I think, since it is working for the first time. Only on the second try it flickr.